# Can any e-ink display be used as a monitor for raspberry pi?

Tags: display, eink

I want to use my raspberry pi as a normal pc / tablet substitute, just for reading purposes with calibre. But instead of connecting it to a normal LCD display, I want to connect it to an e-ink display. It doesn't matter if the refresh time takes longer.

I have seen some projects here and there where people want to make clocks or weather stations. Most of them are using waveshare products. There are some shops on Aliexpress where e-ink displays are sold as kindle / kobo diplay replacements or in general ([link 1](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32223475924.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000013.1.2e361f96XeMvCD&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.169870.0&scm_id=1007.13339.169870.0&scm-url=1007.13339.169870.0&pvid=8d9ba2e8-dd9b-43fb-b56e-25c80898fb15&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.169870.0,pvid:8d9ba2e8-dd9b-43fb-b56e-25c80898fb15,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2336_668%23888%233325%2320_668%232846%238108%231977_668%232717%237562%23456_668%231000022185%231000066059%230_668%233468%2315608%23155), [link 2](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000894206559.html?spm=2114.12010612.8148356.2.3d5f3ef3Zfqsgp)). I'd like to know if they are compatible with raspberry pis.

Comment: At a glance no, because the connectors on those are intended for ports the pi doesn't have.  There might be converters (eg. to the DSI style used on the Pi) but I doubt it.  Without that, presuming that it is feasible, you are looking at a major undertaking to produce something cumbersome (and probably with relatively significant additional costs).

Comment: i think that there is a DIY project on the web that involves the building of a laptop computer with an e-ink display ... here is one https://liliputing.com/2018/10/ultimate-writer-is-a-diy-e-ink-typewriter-with-a-custom-wood-case.html ... there are others